# apex page redirect open desktop layout in saleforce1

Tags: apex, visualforce, publisher-action

im using custom visualforce publisheraction in my controller i used

```
pg = new PageReference('/'+record.id);
pg.setRedirect(true);
```

after insert my record. in salforce1 page redirect but open desktop layout, how can i use sforce navigate url function ?

Answer (score 1):

adi,

PageReference redirect is meant only for full site navigation.

Salesforce1 mobile navigation is handled thru [sforce.one javascript library](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) methods

Since in your case you are directing to the records detail page, you can use the **navigateToSObject** method and pass in the record id.

If you are using this page between both S1 and full site, there are some good references from salesforce on Visualforce best practices to handle both full site and salesforce1 versions

[Salesforce1 Navigation Methods and Page Reference Support](https://help-jupiter.sfdro.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000212840&language=en_US)

[Visualforce Pages That Work in Mobile and Desktop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm)

[VF Best Practices Managing Navigation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm)